# upload heavy file from one server to another server

Tags: file-upload, uploading

I have created a application and integrated api of soundcloud. I firstle i am uploading traks on my server after that to the soundcloud server through cron jobs.

It is working fine for smaller file but not for heavier file.I have posted this problem on google group they replied the following:-

Do you proxy the
download through your server? Can you check there that it is received
correctly

I am unable to understand this. can you ples let me explain this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion.

You have asked soundcloud a problem about an ***upload*** of the file to soundcloud servers, and they have replied about ***download*** of the file from soundcloud.

What they mean is when a user tries to download a file from the soundcloud server, is it going via your server or directly via soundcloud.

Proxy here means the intermediate server - so they are asking is it getting to your server correctly?

I think you need to rephrase your question for them to understand it better - and clarify you mean an upload from your server to soundcloud.